# how to create onitemclick listener to open another listview

Tags: java, android, listview

hi here i displayed methods that are present in the class so now i want when i click
     that methods it has to displays it's parameters in another layout so for that i 
     created another activity and layout but it is not working to connect with with
     onitemclick.

```
public class Listview extends Activity{
       private ListView listView;     
       // public ItemClickListener clicklistener = new ItemClickListener();

private ListView lv;
public static ArrayList<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    Button backButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.methodbackbutton1);
    ((ListView) findViewById (R.id.parameter_listview)).setOnItemClickListener (this);

      OnItemClickListener clicklistener;
    //listView.setOnItemClickListener(clicklistener);
    //listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.parameter_listview);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) 
        {
             // In the following line "v" refers to the View returned by the `getView()` method; meaning the clicked View.
             TextView txtName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.paramlistView1);
             String name = txtName.getText().toString();



             }

        }
    );
  backButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

Comment: You will have to pass your parameters into another activity to show in layout through intent.

Comment: i created intent but we have to give layout.id where should we give that ..

Comment: look at what Mr Dubey wrote. THIS is your way to go...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `intent` for swithcing activity and use `putExtra` to pass value from current activity to next.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) 
        {
             // In the following line "v" refers to the View returned by the `getView()` method; meaning the clicked View.
             TextView txtName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.paramlistView1);
             String name = txtName.getText().toString();
             Intent in = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
             in.putExtra("name" , name);
             startActivity(in);
             }
        }
    );
```

In Second activity `onCreate()` you have to get value from `intent` like below:

```
String name = getIntent().getString("name");
```

Comment: it throws some error . The constructor Intent(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, Class<Parameteractivity>) is undefined

Comment: Post logcat in your question

Comment: at com.api.testapp.Listview$1.onItemClick(Listview.java:45)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6170):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6170):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6170):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)

E/AndroidRuntime( 6170):  at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)

Comment: The constructor Intent(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, Class<Method_TestClass>) is undefined

Comment: this is the issue encounter sir

Answer (score 1):

Try out as below:

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) 
        {
             // In the following line "v" refers to the View returned by the `getView()` method; meaning the clicked View.
             TextView txtName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.paramlistView1);
             String name = txtName.getText().toString();
             startActivity(new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class).putExtra("value",name))); 

             }
        }
    );
```

In your second activity layout get the value from `Intent` in `onCreate()` and show in whichever `View` you want as below:

Write below code in your second activities `onCreate()`

```
     String data=getIntent().getString("value");
```